# AppFabric QuotaExceededException

Tags: windows, caching, appfabric

When trying to insert a large item into the AppFabric cache I get an error

```
 Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException:ErrorCode<ERRCA0016>:SubStatus<ES0001>:The connection was terminated, possibly due to server or network problems or serialized Object size is greater than MaxBufferSize on server. Result of the request is unknown. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (183886080) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element. ---> System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (183886080) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EndReceive(IAsyncResult  result)
 at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.WcfClientChannel.CompleteProcessing(IAsyncResult result)
```

The problem is I can find very little documentation on this issue.
I can see various links discussing the issue all pointing to sites that no longer exist.

e.g.
http://www.biztalkgurus.com/appfabric/b/appfabric-syn/archive/2011/04/19/understanding-the-windows-azure-appfabric-service-bus-quotaexceededexception.aspx

I've also found the following which discusses setting the MaxReceivedMessageSize property.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677250(v=azure.10).aspx

However on my install of AppFabric 1.1 on Windows server I don't have the cmdlet Set-ASAppServiceEndpoint and cannot find where to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

Error not in AppFabric. The service need more size to transmit messsage to other endpoint. You remember this configuration must be the same at both endpoints.